# Cannot cross-compile Xojo for ARM

Tags: chilkat

When I attempt to compile a Xojo application, I get this:

Linking Executable
Fatal: can not read symbol[58719] in file C:\Users\jprov\AppData\Local\Temp\xojo scratch 28260\MyApplication [80364BB8]\Linux_ARM/#userplugins0.o

Does anyone have any ideas ? I can cross-compile Xojo apps for the ARM, but when the Chilkat Xojo plugin is involved, I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier this year, in June, another user had a somewhat similar problem w/ compiling and linking a Xojo app on Linux/ARM.  The solution was to build Chilkat with llvm vs gcc.

It solved the user's problem, so maybe you just need the latest Chilkat build?

Please try this one:  https://chilkatdownload.com/prerelease/chilkat-1200.xojo_plugin

Comment: I just tried that and it did not resolve the problem. The problem remains. I cannot link any program (even the examples) for ARM using the Chilkat Xojo plugin.

Comment: Has there been any progress on this ? I still am not able to compile ANY program for LinuxARM that includes the Chilkat Xojo plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is different, other than I am now using Xojo R4, but the issue has resolved itself. I can now use the LLVM version of the plugin on an ARM processor. Thank you for your help, Matt.